# Build docker image without docker installed

Tags: maven, docker, build

Is it somehow possible to build images without having docker installed. On maven build of my project I'd like to produce docker image, but I don't want to force others to install docker on their machines.

I can think of some virtual box image with docker installed, but it is kind of heavy solution. Is there some way to build the image with some maven plugin only, some Go code or already prepared virtual box image for exactly this purpose?

It boils down to question how to use docker without forcing users to install anything. Either just for build or even for running docker images.

**UPDATE**

There are some, not really up to date, maven plugins for virtual machine provisioning [with vagrant](https://github.com/nicoulaj/vagrant-maven-plugin) or [with vbox](https://github.com/alexec/maven-vbox-plugin). I have found article about building [docker images without docker on basel](https://medium.com/bitnami-perspectives/building-docker-images-without-docker-c619061b13a9)
So far I see two options either I can somehow build the images only or run some VM with docker daemon inside(which can be used not only for builds, but even for integration tests)

Comment: What would the purpose be of building an artifact that they can neither inpsect or run?

Comment: If you have dockerized production, you can use it right away. In case the image holds some application(i.e. on nginx), which is properly unit tested maybe there is no need to run it.

Comment: it is maybe about simplify the usage of docker for other users. They maybe don't want to use it at all, but they should be able to build an image. I read something about building without docker [here](https://medium.com/bitnami-perspectives/building-docker-images-without-docker-c619061b13a9). It is more about being able to somehow skip the "docker install step".

Comment: @Zveratko I think that we're all scratching our heads to your use case. Unless you mean a CI system (remote built and testing), you need at least the Docker client installed to do anything useful.

Comment: Ok, I can understand there is no way to build docker container without docker. So then I need some VM with docker to do all that stuff. Note (I'm using WIN), only way I can see is to create some VM image for virtual box, with preinstalled docker that can be used to build(and additionally for testing), only downside is the size of such image. But if I want to package somehow the Docker there is no other way.

Comment: Nobody mentioned Jib (https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib)  and its maven and gradle plugins ?

Comment: The many ways to build an OCI image without Docker: https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2018/03/the-many-ways-to-build-oci-images/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can create Docker image without Docker being installed.

**Jib Maven and Gradle Plugins**

Google has an open source tool called Jib that is relatively new, but 
quite interesting for a number of reasons. Probably the most interesting 
thing is that you don’t need docker to run it - it builds the image using 
the same standard output as you get from docker build but doesn’t use 
docker unless you ask it to - so it works in environments where docker is 
not installed (not uncommon in build servers). You also don’t need a 
Dockerfile (it would be ignored anyway), or anything in your pom.xml to 
get an image built in Maven (Gradle would require you to at least install 
the plugin in build.gradle).

Another interesting feature of Jib is that it is opinionated about 
layers, and it optimizes them in a slightly different way than the multi-
layer Dockerfile created above. Just like in the fat jar, Jib separates 
local application resources from dependencies, but it goes a step further 
and also puts snapshot dependencies into a separate layer, since they are 
more likely to change. There are configuration options for customizing the 
layout further.

Pls refer this link https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-jib-build-java-docker-images-better

For example with Spring Boot refer https://spring.io/blog/2018/11/08/spring-boot-in-a-container

Comment: This is what I have looking for, although I must say that giving up the docker file is quite uncomfortable. It would be fine to be able to supply own dockerfile if needed.   But so far the closest answer

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the following tools:

1. **Fabric8-maven-plugin** - http://maven.fabric8.io/ - good maven integration, uses a remote docker (openshift) cluster for the builds.
2. **Buildah** - https://github.com/containers/buildah - builds without a docker daemon but does have [other pre-requisites](https://github.com/containers/buildah/blob/master/install.md).

---

### Fabric8-maven-plugin

*The [fabric8-maven-plugin](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-maven-plugin) brings your Java applications on to Kubernetes and OpenShift. It provides a tight integration into Maven and benefits from the build configuration already provided. This plugin focus on two tasks: Building Docker images and creating Kubernetes and OpenShift resource descriptors.*

fabric8-maven-plugin seems particularly appropriate if you have a Kubernetes / Openshift cluster available.  It uses the Openshift APIs to build and optionally deploy an image directly to your cluster.

I was able to [build and deploy](http://maven.fabric8.io/#building-images) their [zero-config spring-boot](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-maven-plugin/tree/master/samples/zero-config) example extremely quickly, no Dockerfile necessary, just write your application code and it takes care of all the boilerplate.

Assuming you have the basic setup to connect to OpenShift from your desktop already, it will package up the project .jar in a container and start it on Openshift. The minimum maven configuration is to add the plugin to your pom.xml build/plugins section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.41</version>
</plugin>
```

then build+deploy using

```
$ mvn fabric8:deploy
```

If you require more control and prefer to manage your own Dockerfile, it can handle this too, this is shown in [samples/secret-config](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-maven-plugin/tree/master/samples/secret-config).

---

### Buildah

*Buildah is a tool that facilitates building Open Container Initiative (OCI) container images. The package provides a command line tool that can be used to:*

- create a working container, either from scratch or using an image as a starting point
- create an image, either from a working container or via the instructions in a Dockerfile
- images can be built in either the OCI image format or the traditional upstream docker image format
- mount a working container's root filesystem for manipulation
- unmount a working container's root filesystem
- use the updated contents of a container's root filesystem as a filesystem layer to create a new image
- delete a working container or an image
- rename a local container

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to force others to install docker on their machines.

If by "*without Docker installed*" you mean **without having to install Docker locally on every machine running the build**, you can leverage the [Docker Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/) which allow you to call a Docker Daemon from a distant host.

> The Docker Engine API is a RESTful API accessed by an HTTP client such
>   as wget or curl, or the HTTP library which is part of most modern
>   programming languages.

For example, the [Fabric8 Docker Maven Plugin](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin#docker-api-support) does just that using the `DOCKER_HOST` parameter. You'll need a recent Docker version and you'll have to configure at least one Docker Daemon properly so it can securely accept remote requests (there are lot of resources on this subject, such as the [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/), [here](https://github.com/IcaliaLabs/guides/wiki/Deploy-and-Secure-a-Remote-Docker-Engine) or [here](https://www.kevinkuszyk.com/2016/11/28/connect-your-docker-client-to-a-remote-docker-host/)). From then on, your Docker build can be done remotely without having to install Docker locally.

Comment: It is actually pretty close, but still you need some setup and moreover the host can be overloaded, if it will be used for integretion testing as well. I thought the layer system is possible to build without docker.

Comment: I see, it seems possible technically but you would have to reproduce the same functionally Docker already provides to build *exactly* the same images. You would eventually end-up programming your own standalone Docker-build-like library. Docker is actually a plumbing of several components as shown here: https://www.docker.com/open-source-0#/software_infrastructure

Comment: A solution may be to use Vagrant and a Vagrantfile with Docker-ready image configured with daemon and API, and with Maven Exec Plugin you can run `vagrant up|halt` before/after your build process. You'll still need to have Vagrant installed though, that just moves your problem somewhere else. If this solution seems possible, tell me I'll edit my answer with details regarding this approach.

Comment: @Zveratko any update on this? ;) I'll be happy to provide a solution for your issue (it's a fun technical challenge)

Comment: Just investigating where to put the VM image. Store it per project in versioning system is nonsense. Maybe pack it as some maven dependency. There are two way one is to prepare image with docker inside and just run it, second is to let i.e. the vagrant plugin to prepare some image and then somehow install the docker. The first option is probably easier.

Comment: With Vagrant and a Vagrantfile you can use an already configured image with Docker. See https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search?q=docker
You could perform needed configuration (i.e. granting access to the daemon port) using a shell provisioning. You won't have to maintain a full image this way, and it will be more portable

Comment: What about boot2docker image? Isn't it the image I'm looking for?

Comment: It might be! Depends on your need, but any image containing Docker may be usable in your context.

Comment: I'm concerned also about the size of the image. What can be the downsides  of using boot2docker I cann't imagine any. Actually I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/2osgl7/vagrant_vs_boot2docker/) usefull.

Comment: I have again evaluated vagrant and I still don't get the difference between docker as vagrant provider vs docker as vagrant provisioner. I have already put here [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394707/vagrant-docker-provider-vs-docker-provisioner) before some time, but still not clear about the meaning. Can you help here?

Answer (score 1):

Google has released [Kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) for this purpose. It should be run as a container, whether in Kubernetes, Docker or gVisor.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problems, and I did not find any solution, thus i developed [odagrun](https://www.odagrun.com), it's a runner for Gitlab with integrated registry api, update DockerHub, Microbadger etc.

OpenSource and has a MIT license.

Ideal to create a docker image on the fly, without the need of a docker daemon nor the need of a root account, or any image at all (image: scratch will do), currrently still in development, but i use it every day.

Requirements

1. project repository on Gitlab
2. an openshift cluster (an openshift-online-starter will do for most medium/small

extract how the docker image for this project was created:

```
# create and push image to ImageStream:
build_rootfs:
  image: centos
  stage: build-image
  dependencies:
    - build
  before_script:
    - mkdir -pv rootfs
    - cp -v output/oc-* rootfs/
    - mkdir -pv rootfs/etc/pki/tls/certs
    - mkdir -pv rootfs/bin-runner
    - cp -v /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt rootfs/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    - chmod -Rv 777  rootfs
  tags:
    - oc-runner-shared
  script:
    - registry_push --rootfs --name=test-$CI_PIPELINE_ID --ISR --config
```